# SVN getting a local history

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, version-control

I use tortoise SVN and IntelliJ IDEA for local development.  The source code is in a SVN repository.
What I want, is something like a local hsitory, that I can work local with history and its basic benefits:
local commit, review history, back and forth in history/revert, merge revisions -> final svn commit

Is ther a tooling to archive this without to much overhead & risk of messing up things. 
Maybe like using the local svn working copy as an "DMZ" between local working and the central SVN repository.

Is there a way to do so? With a simple explanation of the basic steps that are needed.

1) "Check" out form "svn working copy"
2) change something
3) Local commit
4) chang something
5) Local commit
6) chang something
7) Local commit
8) brows local history
9) get point in local history
10) change something
11) local commit
12) sqash hisroty parts
13) commit to "svn working copy" merged changes
14) commit to svn server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using IntelliJ IDEA there is also the option to use the nice feature called **Local History**.
You can find it in menu `VCS -> Local History -> Show Local History`.
Its a simple list of revisions and shows the diffs.
There you can revert to a specific revision or only pic changes form there. There is also the opportunity to put labels on revisions in the local history. For better finding them later.
But keep in mind that *Local History is not a real versioning system* (it can become corrupted on crashes, no branches, ...)!
By default it keeps track of the files for 5 working days. (This can be configured in the IDEA Registry or by a VM argument (`-DlocalHistory.daysToKeep=30`))
I found it to be nice and handy feature.

---

Another option to try would be using **git-svn**. It is more powerful but also more complex. e.g.:
To set it up -> get a local clone (this will take quite an amount of time) and set the git ignores same as the svn ones.

```
git-svn clone -s http://example.com/subversion/repo local/working/with/git-svn/directory
git-svn show-ignore > .gitignore
```

At that point you would work like normal with git on your local machine with commands ...

```
git checkout -b <feature branch>
git add .
git checkout <file name> 
git reset HEAD <file name> 
git commit -a
git checkout master 
git merge <feature branch>
```

To create an work on the new feature branch, add changed files to the index, rest it if you like, commit, back to master branch and merge the changes to the master.

To commit the changes finally to the central svn

```
git -svn rebase 
git -svn dcommit
```

Download SVN changes and apply your local changes on it and then commit it to the SVN .

Answer (score -1):

What you are describing is a better fit for a distributed version control system like `Git` or `Mercurial`.

But if you want to stick with Subversion, you can setup a local SVN repository of your code base (Use TortoiseSVN to do "Create repository here"). Then do periodic `svn merge` from your local to remote.

Comment: How do I get the data form the remote in the local repository?